# Is there a syntax highlighting editor component for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, editor, frameworks, syntax-highlighting, components

I am looking for a syntax highlighting component that I can include in a Mac OS X XCode project to allow editing of Ruby, C++, Lua, etc.

I need a component that is open source or has the source included.

My Google searches didn't turn up much in the way of Mac OS X frameworks or components at all, let alone the type I am looking for.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument](http://github.com/uliwitness/UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument/) (Mac-specific) or [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) (cross-platform and in use in a variety of editors, including Komodo) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Ah...I saw Scintilla but somehow thought it was Win32 only.

Comment: The UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument looks good too, but I wonder about the license.

Comment: The Scintilla page, when I looked at it again for your question, does not appear to mention Mac at all, but I know it's used in Komodo (listed under "Related" on scintilla.org) and I've used Komodo on the Mac.

It looks like another URL for UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument is http://github.com/uliwitness/UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument/ (perhaps more recent--in fact, I'm going to change the URL in my answer) and a README.txt file there has a license block in it that appears (at a quick glance--read for yourself to be sure) to be BSD.

Comment: The UKSyntaxColoredTextDocument license fee is extremely reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use scintilla. http://www.scintilla.org/

Comment: @Bytenik, scintilla was at least carbon version  http://www.mail-archive.com/scintilla-interest@lyra.org/msg01961.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/). I do this in my [SQLite Professional](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlite-professional/id586001240?mt=12) app to highlight user editable queries. It's also fairly simple to setup:

1. In your project, add the CodeMirror contents as a Folder rather than a group.
2. Add the WebKit.Framework to your project.
3. Add a WebView to your nib/xib.

Add the following code:

```
// Load our webview from our local CodeMirror path
NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/CodeMirror/Demo/preview.html", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSString * html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[webView.mainFrame loadHTMLString: html baseURL: url];
```

They also have lots of formats pre-defined, so it works quite well. The one issue I have found with this, is that the native Find dialog does not work when in the context of the WebView.